# TradingChart Example does not work

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new to `Mathematica 10` and I was trying to get one of the examples from Wolfram to work. The example is the following:

```
TradingChart[{"SP500", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}]
```

However, I always get the following error:

```
TradingChart::notdate: "{{2009,1,1},{2009,12,31}} is not a valid date range for \!\(\"TradingChart\"\)."
```

I do not understand how I can modify the date range to get it to work. Maybe one of you could give me a hint in the right direction.

You can also find the examples here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TradingChart.html

Comment: what version?  works for me in 11.1 but not in 10.1 (I get a different error though)

Comment: Version is 10.2

Comment: You are right!!! I tried in Trail version 11.2 and it works. :(   That is really annoying

Comment: `FinancialData` seems to work.. `DateListPlot[FinancialData["SP500", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}]]`  (note one less set of curly brackets ).

Comment: This outputs: DateListPlot[{{Take[{2009, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   931.8}, {Take[{2009, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   927.45}, {Take[{2009, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   934.7}, {Take[{2009, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   906.65}, {Take[{2009, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   909.73}, {Take[{2009, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   890.35}, {Take[{2009, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 
   870.26}, {Take[{2009, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, UpTo[3]], 871.79}, .... But this is getting closer ;)

Comment: ah.. it is trying to use `UpTo` which is a new function not introduced until v10.3 .  Try posting on mathematica.stackexchange.com maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
If[$VersionNumber < 11 , UpTo[3] = 3 ]
TradingChart[{"SP500", {{2009, 1, 1}, {2009, 12, 31}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks! I was trying forever!